# Possibility to get all form inputs from several layers of panels and forms

Tags: java, wicket

Kinda new to wicket and im wondering if its possible to use a AjaxButton in order to get form values from forms within the first form...

For example, using the "ajaxButton" below would it be possible to also get the value of "anothervalue" even though its not in the same form?

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" wicket:id="ajaxButton" />
  <input type="text" wicket:id="aValue" />
  <panel>
      <form>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="anothervalue" />
      </form>
  </panel>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe you could achieve this with an [IVisitor](http://www.mysticcoders.com/blog/add-form-components-to-ajaxtarget-with-ivisitor/).

Comment: This could have been solved faster by just giving it a try honestly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket supports nested forms. When you submit the outer form, the inner one should also processed (validate params, update models).